# How to compare 2 columns in 2 different files and print corresponding line if the column matches

Tags: awk

I have 2 huge files with >8k lines.

file 1:

```
porta side1 13 23
portb side1 56 76
portc side2 67 76
.
.
```

file 2:

```
porta side1 11 45
portb side3 50 72
portc side2 56 66
.
.
```

column 1 in both files are same. I want to compare column 2 in both files and if it is same, I need the line to be printed
required output:

```
porta side1 13 23
portc side2 67 76
```

I tried it with awk, but output is complete file1 (it also prints portb)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}($2 in a)' file1 file2 > output
```

Please help me to correct it to get the required output
also I tried to paste both files together and then comparing the columns:

```
paste file1 file2 > mergefile
awk '{if ($2=$6) { print $0 } }' mergefile
```

the output is again not the required one. It prints same mergefile with updating column2 ($2) with value in $6.
Please help with a solution here.
Thanks

Comment: What delimits the columns? Is `portb side1` a _single_ column? Assuming so, you might want something like: `awk 'FNR==NR {seen[$1" "$2]=1}; FNR!=NR && seen[$1" "$2]' file2 file1`. Hash the first two fields of each line in file2, then print lines in file1 when the same hashes occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' file2 file1
```